# cocoa using WebView load swf file

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, flash

I use webview to load a SWF file in Mac OS X, but it notices "Missing Plug-in".

Here my code:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='overflow:hide;'><object width=\"344\" height=\"298\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"<embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\"%@\" width=\"344\" height=\"298\"/></body></html>", flashLink, flashLink];
[[webView mainFrame]loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
WebPreferences *prefs = [vwWeb preferences];
[prefs setPlugInsEnabled:YES];
```

how can I load this swf?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing by changing another webview's preferences, but try change your preferences before you load the page like this

```
NSString *htmlString = //Your string here
[[webView preferences] setPlugInsEnabled:YES];
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: @karl.winsley I don't know what you did, but I was able to create a quick test project that ran perfectly on my computer.

Comment: I run this on Mac OS X 10.7. What mac version do you implement?

Comment: @karl.winsley 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.2.1, thought I doubt that's the problem.  Check in IB if you ticked off plugins for your WebView

Comment: In IB, the WebView plugins is enabled

Comment: Do you have Flash Player installed? If you're using Google Chrome as your main browser, you may not have it, as it bundles its own version of it.